# allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' error only on my hosted website

Tags: asp.net, windows-hosting

Error:

> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

```
Line 10: </connectionStrings>
Line 11: <system.web>
Line 12: <roleManager enabled="true" />
Line 13: <membership>
Line 14: <providers>
```

> Source File:
>   \Ns2\f\Users\cPanel\jdlferre\public_html\orangefresh\web.config
>   Line: 12

I've looked around the internet with no luck, I don't have any other web.config files on my subfolders, or even anywhere on my website. I don't use IIS so I've scratched that out too...

My website runs fine locally, it's only online that I get this error...

Comment: `\jdlferre\public_html\orangefresh\web.config` is this not a file you have control over?

Comment: Yes, I have control over it... it's the only web.config file in my website.

Comment: When you say you don't use IIS, how are you hosting a website online without IIS?

Comment: you have place this web.config to a subdirectory and there you can not use this option

Comment: DarkHippo: I don't know what you mean (and that is very likely my fault - this is my first ever ASP.NET project that I try to host), I don't know anything about IIS really, I don't have anything IIS on my computer and I used Filezilla to upload my website. 

Aristos: I didn't understand you there, my web.config is on a subdirectory?...

Comment: You don't need IIS on your computer. IIS is the program that the hosting provider will use to run the website on the server you uploaded it to.

Comment: I think Aristos is asking if your web.config is in a sub-directory or in the root of your site. So looking at the URL above, you have the public_html folder, then the orangefresh sub folder. Does the orangefresh subfolder contain all of your website code?

Comment: Yes, the web.config file in in the root folder, all the files and folders for my website are in the orangefresh folder.

Comment: Are there any files in the public_html folder besides the orangefresh folder? If not, try moving all the files to there

Comment: Ok, that now gives me a "Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive." This is also what happened when I tried moving my web.config file around.

Comment: I have this on my web.config file: <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"> , I tried changing my ASP.NET version from 2.0 to 4.0 on my hosts cPanel, still getting the error though...

Answer (score 0):

I would presume that your host is running your site within a sub folder of a website. The website will have a top level web.config in it, various sections of your web.config will then conflict with the parent configuration file.

I would suggest you try replicating that environment locally.

Comment: Well, locally I don't have issues, about replicating the environment - do you mean placing a web.config file a folder or so above my website folder? I've tried that just now without a problem...

Comment: Yes, the top-level web.config will likely have a lot of default configuration sections in it. I would try including a default config file generated by visual studio in a root folder and then place your website in a subfolder within that.

Comment: To clarify, once you have that setup, you should only upload your website to the host (not the top-level config file)

Comment: I just attempted this locally and my website still runs fine... placed a default web.config file a folder above my project, no problem whatsoever... I opened up my website once on the new Visual Studio 2012 trial, it gave me a message about IIS versions, could this have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: You will have to move various sections out of your website config file and into the top-level such as `<authentication>` and `<membership>`

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, that now gives me a "Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute
>   'targetFramework'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive." This
>   is also what happened when I tried moving my web.config file around. –
>   Joao Ferreira 1 min ago

That sounds to me like you're trying to run a .Net 4 or above website under a hosting provider that only supports .net 3.5

You can check by right clicking on the website root in Visual Studio, then going to "property pages" then click "build" (note: that's in VS2010, I don't have 2012, but it's probably quite similar). That should give you target framework information.

If you're using VS2012, then it probably creates a .Net 4 website by default, so it'll probably say .NET Framework 4.

If you're not using any controls that need .Net 4 or above, you can rebuild it in 3.5 and see if that solves the problem.

Otherwise, check with your hosting company to make sure they do host .Net 4 sites. Not all of them do, I've come across that exact problem a couple of months ago.

Comment: My host does have the option on cPanel to run ASP.NET version 4.0

Comment: And yeah, just called up my host and they do support 4.0.

Comment: In that case, make sure it is being build for .Net 4 and not a previous version.

Comment: You can just remove the targetFramework attribute and see if that solves it